# Unable to create non-generic LINQ function within Repository class

Tags: c#, linq, repository

I'm trying to create a Repository for an Object `Page`.

I would like to have non-generic LINQ queries but can't seem to get them working,

I am only able to create them if they are generic and in a helper class, and please let me know if it is recommended to have this type of function in a Helper Class, let me know the reasoning if so.

```
public class PageRepository
{
    public PageViewModel GetPageById(string oid)
    {
        using (var db = new AppDbContext())
        {
            Page page = db.Pages
                //This is what I cannot get working
                .WhereStatusType(StatusType.Published);
                
            return GetPageView(page);
        }
    }
    
    //I would like the below to work
    //Tried generic (below), also non-generic <Page> but doesn't work
    internal static IQueryable<T> WhereStatusType<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, StatusType statusType = StatusType.Published)
        where T : Page
    {
        return query.Where(p => p.StatusType == statusType);
    }
    
}

//Below is working, but don't want it in a helper
public static class PageHelper
{
    internal static IQueryable<T> WhereStatusType<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, StatusType statusType = StatusType.Published)
        where T : Page
    {
        return query.Where(p => p.StatusType == statusType);
    }
}
```

When I attempt to make the IQueryable non-generic, I receive the following errors:

> public class PageRepository has an issue:
>
> Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class

Also:

> 'IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'WhereStatusType' and no extension method 'WhereStatusType' accepting a first argument of type 'IQueryable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I'm sure it is a simple solution, thank you for the help.  Also, if I am approaching this incorrectly, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

## Edit:

While FirstOfDefault() is suggested for the above code, I am also looking to use the function when returning `List<PageViewModel>` (I may have over-simplified the code/example), for example:

```
public List<PageViewModel> GetPages()
{
    using (var context = new AppDbContext())
    {

        List<Page> pages = new List<Page>();
        pages = context.Pages.AsNoTracking()
            .WhereStatusType(StatusType.Published)
            .ToList();

        if (pages != null)
        {
            List<PageViewModel> pageViewModels = new List<PageViewModel>();
            foreach (Page p in pages)
                pageViewModels.Add(GetPageView(p));

            return pageViewModels;
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your helper function takes a parameter called `statusType` that isn't actually used in the function -- is that intentional?

Comment: No, the example is slightly off, I will update.

Comment: You should use  normal method not extension method from your question's description.

Comment: What do you mean by `normal method` vs `extension method`. Do you have a quick example?

Comment: In you case I will suggest you can use linq `where` on the your code,because `WhereStatusType<T>` use `where` directly.

Comment: @D-Shih has a good point – if all you're doing is checking the value of one property, there's no particular gain to writing your own function. But if you think `WhereStatusType()` might get more complicated, and if it will be used in more than one place, you can either use an extension method in a helper class, as you have above, or a non-extension method, as in my answer below.

Comment: The plan is to future proof the Repositories for all my data, while I was against the Helper Class at first, based on all the answers and comments, Helper Classes may prove to be the best approach, I'll be able to extend the logic if needed but also separate it from the actual repository classes, if organized properly, I'll be able make changes to may other repositories if logic changes throughout the application. Thank you to all.

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you exactly what's going on here. If you want an extension method -- a method whose first parameter uses the `this` keyword, like your example -- then it needs to be defined in a non-generic static class, like your `PageHelper`.

If you don't like that approach, you could define a non-extension method, something like this:

```cs
public class PageRepository
{
    public PageViewModel GetPageById(string oid)
    {
        using (var db = new AppDbContext())
        {
            Page page = GetPagesWithStatus(db.Pages, StatusType.Published);

            return GetPageView(page);
        }
    }

    internal IQueryable<Page> GetPagesWithStatus(IQueryable<Page> query, StatusType statusType)
    {
        return query.Where(p => p.StatusType == statusType);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As **@asherber** mentioned, your LINQ query isn't right. You are comparing `p.Alias` to `p.Alias`

Also, it looks like you want a `FirstOrDefault()` in there.

Comment: Correct. p.Alias to p.Alias was incorrect, I have updated the OP.  In this example, FirstOrDefault() is a good idea, but I am also looking to use it when I get a List<Page> pages as well.

Comment: Asherber is correct. You can only create extension methods in static classes.